# “Error getting identity: Forbidden” when trying to add Google account to fedora online-accounts

Tags: fedora, gnome3

I am using fedora 18 32 bit and wanted to add my google account through its gnome online account.

I click on "Online Accounts" and then enter my Google username and password. 
I have enabled 2 step verification to my google. I get the verification code, everything goes well,

After that I get

> The GNOME application on your computer is requesting access to your
>   Google Account for the product(s) listed below

I click on grant access.

It gives an error and says:

"Error getting identity: Forbidden"

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

GNOME 3.6 (the version in Fedora 18) does not support 2-factor authentication because there was a long time when Google did not support Oauth2 (the login mechanism involving a browser) for calendars.

The [workaround is described online](http://kparal.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/gnome-3-6-gnome-online-accounts-and-google-two-factor-authentication/), and worked for me.

In short:

1. Generate app-specific password
2. Delete GOA passwords from seahorse, and logout / login
3. Manually add application-specific password to stored GOA password string
4. Log out & log in again